# React Native crash android in WebView with UnsatisfiedLinkError to use 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android, crash, android-webview, react-native

I have an error in the production mode in React Native, especially on Xiaomi with Android 7 system. It is not possible to catch this crash on the develop mode.

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/system/app/Chrome/Chrome.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmonochrome.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
       at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadAlreadyLocked(LibraryLoader.java:89)
       at org.chromium.base.library_loader.LibraryLoader.loadNowOverrideApplicationContext(LibraryLoader.java:35)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.I(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:61)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:31)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:198)
       at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:180)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:58)
       at okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar.loadForRequest(JavaNetCookieJar.java:61)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer.loadForRequest(ReactCookieJarContainer.java:44)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:84)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

I think the cause of it WebView's version incompatibility. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Do you know the exact model(s) of Xiaomi as Android 7 was 64-bit?

Comment: I can not know it, because crash report comes from firebase crashlytics with only stacktrace, OS and phones model

Comment: So what does brand & model say in the Data tab?

Comment: Do you mean in crashlytics? Just OS, phone model. But there is no any information about of bits of this device

Comment: @jocoders I am facing the same error, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @instanceof no, I could not find the real cause of this issue

Comment: same here, I am trying to load subclass of webview in my app. It only occured for a specific device.